# How can I define the default application to open when I connect my iPhone to Ubuntu?

Tags: iphone, ubuntu

When I plug in my iPhone 7 to my PC running Ubuntu 22.04 using a USB cable

then Ubuntu currently starts the app **Shotwell**

but with this app, I’m not able to import the pictures from my iPhone. I’m used to using **digiKam** instead, which works better for me.

How can I change the Ubuntu system settings so that Shotwell won’t autostart anymore, but digiKam will run instead?

In the system settings, under *Removable Media*, the settings for *Photos* is already set to *digiKam*.